# Second order gradient of a non-linear element-wise function and a Hadamard product

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, hadamard-product

I am applying the mean value theorem to an analysis, but I am running into problems computing the second derivative.

let:

$$ J = d^Tf(Wx) $$

with $f$ a generic continuous and differentiable element-wise function, a matrix $W$, and vectors $x$ and $d$.

As part of an application of the mean value theorem:
$$ \nabla_WJ - \nabla_{W^\prime}J = [\nabla^2_Z J] [W - W^\prime] $$
with $Z = \eta W + (1 - \eta) W^\prime$ for some $0 \leq \eta \leq 1$ I need to know $\nabla^2_Z J$

So the question is, how do I compute $\nabla_Z^2J$? For other reasons I happen to know the first derivative:

$$ \nabla^2_Z J = \frac{\partial}{\partial Z}\frac{\partial}{\partial Z} J \\
= \frac{\partial}{\partial Z}[(d \odot f^\prime(Zx))x^T] \\
$$

Although I am familiar with the $\text{vec}$ operator/notation for higher order derivatives, I got stuck with the new hadamard product in there.

(As a side note - I am only 60% sure my application of the mean value theorem in this way is valid, so any guidance you can offer about that would also be really appreciated!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the variables
$$\eqalign{
 Z &= \eta W + (1-\eta)U \cr
 y &= Zx &\implies dy&=dZ\,x\cr
 f &= f(y) \cr
 f' &= f'(y)   &\implies df&=f'\odot dy \cr
 f'' &= f''(y) &\implies df'&=f''\odot dy \cr
 \Gamma &= b^Tf = b:f \cr
}$$ where $dy$ is the differential of $y$ and a colon represents the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
Some further notational conventions. Uppercase latin letters stand for matrices, lowercase latin for vectors, and greek letters for scalars. And for convenience, lowercase and uppercase versions of the same letter stands for a vector and its corresponding diagonal matrix, i.e.
$$B = {\rm Diag}(b)$$

First, let's find the differential and gradient of that last variable
$$\eqalign{
d\Gamma &= b:df \cr
   &= b:f'\odot dy \cr
   &= b\odot f':dy \cr
   &= b\odot f':dZ\,x \cr
   &= (b\odot f')x^T:dZ \cr
G = \nabla_Z\Gamma &= (b\odot f')x^T \cr
}$$
Now let's find the differential of $G$
$$\eqalign{
dG &= (b\odot df')x^T \cr
   &= (b\odot f''\odot dy)x^T \cr
   &= F''B\,dy\,x^T \cr
   &= F''B\,dZ\,xx^T \cr
}$$
This differential is the quantity that we are interested, so I won't go on to rearrange this into a hessian (which in this case is a 4th order tensor).

Now evaluate the differential for $dZ=(W-U)$
$$\eqalign{
\nabla^2_Z\Gamma : (W-U)
 &= F''B\,(W-U)\,xx^T \cr
 &= {\rm Diag}(f''\odot b)\,(W-U)\,xx^T \cr
}$$
We also want to evaluate $d\Gamma$ for $dZ=\eta dW$
$$\eqalign{
d\Gamma
 &= G:\eta\,dW \cr
 &= \eta G:dW \cr
\nabla_W\Gamma &= \eta G \cr
}$$
and for $dZ=(1-\eta)dU$
$$\eqalign{
d\Gamma
 &= G:(1-\eta)\,dU \cr
 &= (1-\eta)G:dU \cr
\nabla_U\Gamma &= (1-\eta)G \cr
}$$
I'll leave it to you to determine how these quantities can be related through a mean value theorem.

**Note that** $\,\{f'(y),\,f''(y)\}\,$ are the first and second derivatives of a scalar function $f(\gamma)$ which are applied element-wise to a vector argument $y.\,\,$ They are not equal to $\,\{\nabla_yf,\,\nabla^2_yf\}\,$ as I had in my initial post.

Comment: Thank you! When you apply the differential to G $dG = (b \odot df^\prime)x^T$, how is it that you were able to apply the right side differential only to $f^\prime$?

Comment: Actually, $db=0$ and $dx=0$.  So formally, you can include them if you wish. But then you will immediately drop them since they equal zero.

Comment: Also, when you evaluate the differential $dZ = (W - U)$ do you actually mean $dZ = (\eta W - \eta U)$? I just would have expected $\eta$ to appear in $\nabla_Z^2 \Gamma$

Comment: Maybe.  You'll need to tweak my answer (like that) in order to make it satisfy a mean-value relationship.

Comment: One last question (I think) - I would have expected $\nabla_Z^2 \Gamma$ to be a 4th order tensor, or a 2Z x 2Z matrix (if using the vec operator) but our result here is that $\nabla_Z^2 \Gamma$ is the same size as Z, is this ok?

Comment: $\nabla^2_Z\Gamma$ is a 4th order tensor, but $(\nabla_Z^2\Gamma):dZ$ is a 2nd order tensor (i.e. a matrix). And that is the quantity that you are ultimately interested in.  You could derive the expression for the tensor, but then you would immediately contract it with some expression for $dZ$.  It's far simpler to substitute the desired expression directly into the differential of $dG$.

Comment: I should have seen it before - but it's clear that in order to use $\nabla_Z^2 \Gamma$ in any mean-value theorem like $\nabla_U \Gamma - \nabla_V \Gamma =  \nabla_Z^2 \Gamma [U - V] $, it is going to have to be the same dimensions as $U$ - but now I'm not sure why we are evaluating it for $dZ$, and what motivated you to choose $dZ = W - U$ . 

Maybe it has to do with my misunderstanding of the notation you are using for $:$? Something like: 
$$
\nabla_Z^2 \Gamma : (W - U) = \nabla_W \Gamma - \nabla_U \Gamma 
$$